# substで作ったdriveに対してDirectory.GetDirectoriesすると例外が発生する

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio

Win7Pro＋Visual Studio Community 2013で以下のようなcodeを書いたところD driveに対する処理で例外が発生して取得できません。解決のためにご助力ください。

---

Cは通常のHDD、DはCの任意のpathをsubstで仮想driveとしたものです。

`subst d: c:\tmp\d`

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string drvC = "c:\\";
    string drvD = "d:\\";
    var foldersC = Directory.GetDirectories(drvC);
    var foldersD = Directory.GetDirectories(drvD); // DirectoryNotFoundException発生
}
```

上記のようなC#のcodeを実行すると、D driveに対しての処理を行うところで例外が発生してしまいます。  
同じことを、Win7Pro＋Visual Studio Pro 2013環境で実行してみたところ例外が発生しませんでした。  
おそらくCommunityに依存していると思うのですが、Proで実現できていることからどうにか対処できないかと悩んでおります。  
正直、どうアプローチして良いかも分からず、半分途方に暮れています。何かご存知の方が居られましたら、教えていただけるとありがたいです。

```
場所 System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
場所 System.IO.FileSystemEnumerableIterator`1.CommonInit()
場所 System.IO.FileSystemEnumerableIterator`1..ctor(String path, String originalUserPath, String searchPattern, SearchOption searchOption, SearchResultHandler`1 resultHandler, Boolean checkHost)
場所 System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(String path)
場所 ConsoleApplication1.Program.Main(String[] args)
場所 System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
場所 System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
場所 Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
場所 System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
場所 System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
場所 System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
場所 System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
場所 System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

[image: DirectoryNotFoundException発生dialog]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Visual StudioをAdministratorに昇格して実行していませんか?(タイトルバーに (Administrator) とついた状態)
もしそうであればデバッグ実行時も昇格した状態となるのでWindowsの仕様でsubstしたパスが見えなくなります。

Comment: おっしゃる通りでした。  
起動時に常にadmin状態で利用するように変更していたのを忘れていました。  
たすかりました。ありがとうございました。

Comment: 常に管理者としてアプリケーションを実行したい場合には、アプリケーションマニフェストファイルを追加した後、`app.manifest`ファイル内で`requiredExecutionLevel`ノードの`level`を`requireAdministrator`と設定してビルドするとよいと思います。

[常に管理者としてアプリケーションを実行させるには？](http://www.atmarkit.co.jp/fdotnet/dotnettips/958uacmanifest/uacmanifest.html) などの記事も参考になるかと。

Answer (score 4):

下記のレジストリを使えばAdministratorでも見える仮想ドライブが作れますよ(詳細はググってください)
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\DOS Devices

Comment: 情報ありがとうございます。  
『HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\DOS Devices』に『文字列値』を新規追加。  
値の名前に『D:』、値のデータに『\??\c:\tmp\d』と設定してやると  
`subst d: c:\tmp\d`
と同等の効果が得られますね。  
で、確かに管理者権限で実行したVisualStudioからGetDirectoriesやっても例外が発生しませんでした。  
有益な情報の提供ありがとうございました。